# Relations between Inequivalent spin structures and sections of their associated spinor bundles.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Let's say I have a closed Riemannian manifold $m$ that admits $p$ spin structures each with a section of the associated spinor bundle $\psi_{p}$.

Let us suppose our manifold of interest $M$ is the connected sum of $k$ manifolds described above $M=\#_{k} m_{k}$

For example, this might be a prime decomposition of a closed three-manifold.

**Question:**

How can we decompose the spin structure (or, more to the point, section of the associated spinor bundle) on $M$ to reflect the components of it's prime decomposition?

Say for example we have $m=S^{1}\times S^{2}$ which admits two spin structures $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$. For a connected sum $M=\#_{k}\left(S^{1}\times S^{2}\right)$  The set of spin structures on $M$ will be in bijection with the free product of the set of spin structures on each of the $m$. (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4211728/number-of-inequivalent-spin-structures-on-k-s2-times-s1) )

I would expect (intuitively) then that the section $\Psi(M)$ of a particular spin structure on M to be of the form

$\Psi(M)=\psi(m_{1})\psi(m_{2})....\psi(m_{k-1})\psi(m_{k})$

Where each $\psi\left(m_{k}\right)$ is a section of one of the two spin structures on the kth $S^{1}\times S^{2}$. How would I go about showing such a result is true (if it is) in general?